# Import Session not working

Tags: javascript, session, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

In my Ember App I want to extend Ember Simple Auth's Session Object (I'm using the Ember CLI Addon). That's why I import it like stated in the docs:

`import Session from 'simple-auth/session';`

When I try to build my app the console logs a file not found error.

I can import the LoginControllerMixin with:

`import LoginControllerMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/login-controller-mixin';`

Is anyone else experiencing this problem or got a clue what could cause this issue?

Comment: what does the 'simple-auth' folder look like?

Comment: Well it has the ember-cli plugin folder structure. There is no session file or mixins folder if that's what you're asking. It's an AMD build so in the simple-auth.js file it defines the 'simple-auth/session' which I should be able to import like I did with the mixins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a known bug in the Ember Simple Auth Addon (https://github.com/simplabs/ember-cli-simple-auth/issues/1) - for now please install the addon directly from the github repository.

Comment: Thanks, will do! I didn't look for closed issues in the repo -.- Cheers from Linz!